# How to know the original values of my data from the contour plot of copula

Tags: copula

Suppose I have a data with Gaussian copula with ($\rho =0.8$). Suppose further the contour[image: Here] plot is as follows:

My question is:

How can I interpret the result with respect to my original values? For example, suppose that the first variable is the temperature and the second one is the bike rental. Suppose that I would like to explain at what values these variables become independent, from the plot. For example, I can say that these two variables are positively correlated at the interval $[0.4,0.6]$ (for example).

Now I would like to know if there is a way that I can say what is the corresponding temperature? That is, what is the corresponding temperature for $[0.4,0.6]$?

Comment: You don't have the information to do this.  You need the maps from your original variables to the $(u_1,u_2)$ coordinates in the image.

Comment: @whuber Thank you so much for your comment. Is there a way to do so? Thanks.

Comment: Yes: review the process you used to produce the copula.  The initial step *must* construct those two maps.  There's no other way.

Comment: @whuber thank you again. I really appreciate your help. However, I really do not get your comment. I just use `pobs` to get copula data and then I plot the contour. If I plot my original data then, it is not helpful.

Comment: You will need to consult your software documentation to learn how to extract this information.

Comment: You have your original data, and you also have your pseudo-data. It's done.